# Does negative energy density (i.e. weak energy condition violation) create closed timelike curves?

Tags: general-relativity, energy, spacetime, causality, closed-timelike-curve

I remember reading something about Stephen Hawking denying the fact you can't make CTC's ([Closed Timelike Curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_timelike_curve)) without [weak energy condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_energy_condition) violation.  If this is true, where do the light cones point to in the $t$ direction?

[image]

On the end of the right and left, the cone points up (future) but near the cylinder it tilts. In a region with negative energy density, do the cones tilt all the way to the $-t$ direction?

Comment: Where do what light cones point to? Is there a specific scenario you are referring to? I assume T is timelike. Perhaps include more information?

Comment: Like in this image, http://inspirehep.net/record/1262683/files/Tipler2.png                      On the end of the right and left, the cone points up (future) but near the cylinder it tilts.  In a region with negative energy density, do the cones tilt all the way to the -t direction?

Comment: Weak energy condition is a property of the stress energy tensor, which you should get by computing the Einstein Tensor. All you gave in the question is a picture, from which is not possible to answer if it does violate or not WEC. On the other hand, you don't need to have the future directed light cones pointing in the $-t$ direction if you want closed causal curves, as the picture shows.

Comment: very good question!

Answer (score 6):

Stephen Hawking proved that closed timelike curves cannot be created in a finite system without using exotic matter. The Tippler cylinder doesn't use exotic matter, but it can create CTCs because it's infinite in length and therefore isn't a finite system.

I think the proof was in [his paper on the Chronology Protection Conjecture](http://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.46.603).

Comment: reenie thanks for this answer, and the proof(link) , +1.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem mentioned here, that in a finite range exotic matter, violating the energy conditions is necessary to form CTCs, i.e. that spacetime is suitable for time travel, is **simply not true**. Whoever supposedly proved it.

It has long been *known that regular counterexamples, i.e. finite time machine spacetimes with normal matter, satisfying the energy conditions, are possible.* For example this:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0503077.pdf